# HasMany Mapping but getting one element or get some of

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual int CategoryOrder { set; get; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<News> LatestNews { set; get; }
}

public sealed class CategoryMap :ClassMap<Category>
{

    public CategoryMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.CategoryOrder);
        HasMany(x => x.LatestNews);
    }

}

        IRepository<Category> newsRepo = new NHibernateRepository<Category>();

        using(var session = newsRepo.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = session.Query<Category>().OrderBy(x => x.CategoryOrder);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

I have this category class Which I want to display a (only one) News per category. Is this correct mapping? or should i change it to `Map`

When i run this, it gets all the news per category. But i want the latest news per category (only one). I can get the latest news by querying `News.DateUpdated`.

How should i change the query to get one news per category?

or how do I get some of the News? ie: limit the number of news I can query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have your cake and eat it too. You have a list of News items, so just leave that. But add in another property that gets just the News item you want.

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual int CategoryOrder { set; get; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<News> AllNews { set; get; }
    public virtual News LatestNews 
    {
        get
        {
            // probably needs some work
            return this.AllNews.OrderByDescending(n => n.SomeDateField).Take(1);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class CategoryMap :ClassMap<Category>
{

    public CategoryMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.CategoryOrder);
        HasMany(x => x.AllNews);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lazy mode extra to achieve this,

```
public News GetLatestNews(Category cat)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.CurrentSession;
    var news = session.CreateFilter(cat.LatestNews , "order by categoryorder").SetFirstResult((page - 1)  * pageSize).SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(1).List().FirstOrDefault();

    return news;
}
```

however if you try to access the LatestNews collection directly, this won't be of any use as it will load all the news objects associated with Category from db which would lower the performance.